# Why I can't move to next command line or run the query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I tried to run this in My SQL server 5.0 and then suddenly `->`changed to `">`
The code I tried to run was:-

```
mysql> insert into gabs
-> VALUES
-> (
->    10,100,98,17,'M','Delhi','Sunil'
-> ),
-> (
->    2,101,95,17,'F','Pune','Neha'
-> ),
-> (
->    15,400,90,17,'M',null,'Amit'
-> ),
-> (
->     6,401,98,18,'M','Haryana','Parth'
-> ),
-> (
->     17,403,98,18,'F',"Chennai','Kamal'
"> ),
"> (
">     18,201,95,18,'M','Delhi','Chita'
"> );
"> \c
">
"> \c;
"> /c
"> /c;
">
```

I even used clear it but it just added a new line each time, I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: `17,403,98,18,'F',"Chennai','Kamal'`, in this line you have given `"` before `chennai` which is causing problem. it should be `'` instead. You should notice that from that line onward your prompt has been changed from `->`  to `">`.

Comment: first thanks a lot for solution ,second but is there a way to move to next command line because I have to exit it everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AkhileshMishra mentioned, the single `"` is causing the problem, replacing it with `'` will solve your problem.

Regarding the "moving to next command line", psql keeps on adding on a SQL query before execution, until it finds a logical endpoint. In your case, you used single `"` for which it kept on trying to find a closing `"`. That's why you are not able to run clear command or any other command for that matter.

You can try putting a `"` and `;` to show that you are done writing your query, then psql will identify the syntax error in your query and simply shows that. After which you will be able to run a new command.

Hope it make sense for you, let me know if you still have any doubt.

Comment: Just close typo questions

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273266/do-we-really-need-to-keep-closed-typo-questions-with-accepted-upvoted-answers

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am still unsure of your action, as there is another answer as well with a score > 0. Also, I don't think this is just a typo question. It's true that OP made a typo mistake but OP was not able to understand the real reason why he is not able to type in a new command, which is mentioned in the question's title, and the same is answered by me and @Bill. Also, I think this could be helpful to future users as well.

Comment: the OP even asked the same thing in the question's comment section after it has been pointed out that there was a typo.

Comment: yes definitely it can be helpful to others also who just started practicing mysql!!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: the way to finish the command is to end your string.

You started a string by typing `"`. That string never ended, because you didn't type the end `"` for the string. The string goes on, as you type newlines, until you finish it with an ending `"`.

```
mysql> insert into mytable set t = "a string
    "> more string
    "> even more string
    "> end of the string";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

The same behavior exists for `'` delimiters.

MySQL uses both `"` and `'` as string delimiters by default, but a given string must use the same quote character for both start and end. Once you start a string with either type of quote character, you should end the string with the same type of quote.